# Ecto updating associations has_one belongs_to

Tags: ecto

I must be making it overly complex, but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around a simple issue.

Say I have two tables, `global_users` and `local_users`:

```
create table(:global_users, primary_key: false) do
  add :id, :integer, primary_key: true
  add :local_user_id, references(:local_users)
  ...
end

create table(:local_users, primary_key: false) do
  add :id, :integer, primary_key: true
  add :global_user_id, references(:global_users)
  ...
end

@primary_key {:id, :integer, autogenerate: false}
schema "global_users" do
  has_one :local_user, Local.User
  ...
end

@primary_key {:id, :integer, autogenerate: false}
schema "local_users" do
  belongs_to :global_user, Global.User
  ...
end
```

Programmatically, I'll first create a global_user, then create a local_user, then I need to associate the two after the fact.

E.g., given an existing, valid `global_user` and an existing, valid `local_user`, how would I associate an existing `local_user` to an existing `global_user`?

Once I add a `has_one`, I no longer have access to the foreign key itself (e.g. there is no `%Global.User{:local_user_id}` to update, only an association!).

Again, I know this seems simple, and I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I was thinking about the incorrectly. When you have a `has_one`, it really just a reference that potentially saves you a join later.

e.g. there is no `local_user_id` in the `global_user` table, but you'd query it like:

```
Repo.all from u in Global.User, preload: [:local_user]
```

which then fetches a match based on how you define the `has_one`:

```
has_one :local_user, Local.User, foreign_key: :global_user_id
```

Makes sense now.

Of course, if you want to limit the fields returned, you still have to get complicated...